# Docker (rails) - Changes in server side code, require restart app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I'm using a windows 10 machine.  I'm also running a docker container that is running a rails application.  Whenever I make a change to any server side code (i.e controllers or models) I'm required to do a docker restart app.

However my friend is using the same container on his apple machine but when he makes changes to any server side code he does not have to restart his app.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails has a configuration option (`config.cache_classes`) that specifies whether or not your application code should be cached in memory between requests. Having this option set to `true` will require you to restart your app if you make changes; having it set to `false` reloads your code on every request, so you don't have to restart.

It is recommended to set this to `false` in the *development* environment only, because Rails works faster if it doesn't have to reload your code every time it starts processing a request. In production, you should leave it set to `true`.